# facebook permissions for images in flex application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flex4

I am developing one facebook application, which i hav to use in my project to fetch images from user's account,

[image]

Now everything is working fine, i am able to login, this window comes for the first time to asking for permission (allow), but it's only asking for "Access my basic information"

I want to ask u , how to make it access "Access my photos and videos", coz when the application will ask for this second permission, then only i'll b able to fetch the images from someone's account in to my flex application

If any one for you has devloped the same application , so please mail me the project archive, coz ma project is about to deliver, and this thing is stopping it

Thanx in advance

Ankur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions , basically you will need to add user_photos  in your permission array and pass it to the request, btw what are you using at your backend ?? php ??

Comment: yaa u r ryt, actually i m using one old api of facebook, i read this about permisson thr, i m not using grpah api, i think i have to use the graph now, thanx bro